# How do I register an event for a raphael elements created through js?

Tags: raphael

Say I have n objects (say rectangles) whose size and position were randomly created when the user pushes a button.  How do I register a click event in Raphael such that I know which rectangle/object was clicked on when the user clicks on one of the rectangles?  The trick here is that n number are created inside of a loop.  I need to be able to handle when any of the rectangles is clicked on so that I can perform some operation (eg. change the color of the clicked on rectangle to blue.)  Here is the code for creating the rectangles:

```
for (var i=1;i<3;i++) {
  x = Math.floor((Math.random()*200)+1);
  y = Math.floor((Math.random()*200)+1);
  width = Math.floor((Math.random()*25)+1) + 25;
  height = Math.floor((Math.random()*100)+1) + 50;
  r1 = paper.rect(x,y,width,height).attr({fill:"red"});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I found it in another posting.  That's just the way it is...you look and look and post here and then you find the answer:

I simply need to add the following handler inside the loop after the rectangle is created:

```
 r1.click(function() { this.attr({fill:'blue'}); });
```

Thanks to:  http://jsfiddle.net/CHUrB/298/